# Bootstrap still not showing in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have added all bootstrap links and scripts that were suggested, cleared cache, and added my server to IE security. The bootstrap elements are still not showing. What am I missing? Anyone how to get past this?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" content="IE=8" content="IE=9" content="IE=10" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> JLB Artistry </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Sorry Bootstrap code not working properly in the code block so I am not including it.

Comment: jquery needs to come before bootstrap, but if the styles aren't even coming in that's not the only issue

Comment: You should only have  one `content` attribute on your `X-UA-Compatible ` tag. IE is probably in IE7 mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I believe you need to add this to functions.php where you enqueue Bootstrap scripts

```
/**
 * Add Respond.js for IE
 */
if( !function_exists('ie_scripts')) {
function ie_scripts() {
    echo '<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->';
    echo ' <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn\'t work if you view the page via file:// -->';
    echo ' <!--[if lt IE 9]>';
    echo ' <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>';
    echo ' <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>';
    echo ' <![endif]-->';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'ie_scripts');
} // end if
```

download the script from here and include it in your theme:
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond
Unzip the download and move the respond.min.js file into your /js/ directory

I also believe you shouldn't add those src into your header.

I recently added Bootstrap Support to my theme, 
and the only I have had to add to my header is

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I reccomend http://bootstrapwp.com TUT's, but they're paid.
But it's worth spent money!

Here you can read why you shouldn't enqueue to header.php
http://wpshout.com/everything-custom-scripts-styles-wordpress/

Comment: Not sure your answer works, but I did realize I was missing the if statement part in the include. Thank you for your help. :) I changed to this. It is working now. <meta charset="utf-8">
                     < <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

I changed to this. It is working now. `<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></…; <script src="oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></…; <script src="oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></…; <![endif]-->`